# ARIMA(0,0,3) fitted values and residuals in R

Tags: r, arima, moving-average

I am trying to understand the residuals returned from a fitted ARIMA(0,0,3) model. I simulated a time series and recovered the parameters:

```r
set.seed(seed = 1)
x <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(0,0,3), ma = c(0.8, 0.6, 0.4)), n = 1000)
x.ma <- arima(x = x, order = c(0, 0, 3), method = 'CSS')
x.ma

Call:
arima(x = x, order = c(0, 0, 3), method = "CSS")

Coefficients:
         ma1     ma2     ma3  intercept
      0.7903  0.5659  0.3922    -0.0229
s.e.  0.0307  0.0351  0.0319     0.0896
```

So far, so good. The recovered parameters are close to the "true" parameters.
I can also back into the white noise terms and recalculate the time series.

And how do I interpret the `residuals(x.ma)` relative to those predicted values? Specifically, how do I relate those values to the simulated data and my fitted values?

Comment: Welcome to CV. The function/method question is off topic here. The second question about interpretation would benefit from a simple, clear example of the residuals and an explanation of what specifically you mean by "interpret ... relative."

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I removed the first question and tried to add a bit more detail.